# The type MultipartEntity is deprecated

Tags: java, apache

The documentation says the [`org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html)  class is deprecated. Could anybody please suggest me an alternative ?

I am using this in my code like this:

```
entity.addPart("params", new StringBody("{\"auth\":{\"key\":\""
            + authKey + "\"},\"template_id\":\"" + templateId + "\"}"));
entity.addPart("my_file", new FileBody(image));
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If you read the docs carefully, you'll notice that you should use [`MultipartEntityBuilder`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html) as an alternative.

For example:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();        

/* example for setting a HttpMultipartMode */
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

/* example for adding an image part */
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(image)); //image should be a String
builder.addPart("my_file", fileBody); 
//and so on
```

Note that there are several constructors for the [`FileBody`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html) class, by which you can provide *mimeType*, *content type*, etc.

After you're done with passing *build instructions* to the builder, you can get the built [`HttpEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html?is-external=true) by invoking the [`MultipartEntityBuilder#build()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html) method:

```
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
```

Comment: Filebody now can't accept image as String only accept file .. please update the answer to be as last version from mime .. thank you in advance

Comment: Can i ask you when i post image as multipartfile .. should i set header for httppost as 
httppost.setheader("Content-Type",
      "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
some thing like this ?

Comment: Usually it's not painful to provide headers. This info can be useful on the server-side. Ofcourse, what exact headers and when, depends on the particular thing you need to implement. If you have some specific case, which you need help with, I suggest to ask a new question and this way you will get the attention of more people

Comment: Now, MultipartEntityBuilder is not longer part of Android, as API 23. How to deal with multipart/form-data in that case?

Comment: @webo80, probably [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) can be helpful.

Comment: @kocko thanks anyway, but it was not helpful for me, it only indicates some guidelines, not at much technical level

Comment: `HttpEntity` is also deprecated now. So can't use `builder.buid()`. What is alternative?

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150184/httpentity-is-deprecated-on-android-now-whats-the-alternative) might be helpful

Comment: How do you construct a [customBodyPart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672604/how-can-i-get-a-custom-content-disposition-line-using-apache-httpclient/20679480#comment110764259_20679480) using `MultipartEntityBuilder`?

Comment: @LeiYang, by calling the `MultipartEntityBuilder#addPart(FormBodyPart bodyPart)` method

Comment: i cannot. error is  **'addPart(org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart)' is not public in 'org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder'. Cannot be accessed from outside package**

Comment: It's public (open the documentation and check it). Probably there's an issue with your project setup.

Answer (score 6):

I still see so many tutorials still using the deprecated APIs which is what lead me to this post. For the benefit of future visitors (until this API gets deprecated ;) )

```
File image = "...."; 
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(image);
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                         .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                         .addTextBody("params", "{....}")
                         .addPart("my_file", fileBody);
HttpEntity multiPartEntity = builder.build();

String url = "....";
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(multiPartEntity);
...
```

Comment: HttpEntity is depricated

Comment: it's only deprecated for android sdk.  it's still just fine to use anywhere else.  org.apache.commons.HttpEntity is not deprecated.

Comment: what's difference between `addTextBody` and `addPart`?

Comment: addPart is private.

Comment: @TrevorHart as of latest version [4.5.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime), `addPart` still seems to be a public API, see latest [API docs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html)

Comment: It could be the version I'm using, will look into this.