# MultipartEntity in HTTP mime is deprecated

Tags: java, apache

I have an MultipartEntity declared like this:

```
MultipartEntity httpEnt = new MultipartEntity();
httpEnt.addPart("Test", new StringBody("test", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

Then I make a rest call like this

```
HttpPost http = new HttPost(url);
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
http.setEntity(httpEnt);
httpClient.execute(http);
```

The MultipartyEntity seems to be deprecated and not working. I was considering using HttpEntity like this:

```
HttpEntity httpEnt = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart("test", new StringBody(....)).build();
```

the problem with this is I want to add multiple parts in different methods and then later build. It seems like if I do it this way I will need to attach all parts at once and build in one line of code. Can I still use the deprecated one? A better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like if I do it this way I will need to attach all parts at once and build in one line of code.

You don't need to do it all on one line.  The `MultipartEntityBuilder.create()` call returns a builder object that you can assign to a variable, and then call methods on, one at a time as separate statements.  Then finally call the `build()` method to get the `HttpEntity`.

(You don't *have* to use the "fluid" idiom in your code if you don't want to.)

> Can I still use the deprecated one?

Yes (probably) ... but it is a good idea to move to the new way of building and representing the multi-part entity.  At some point the deprecated API may be removed<sup>1</sup>, and that will cause version dependency problems for you, and/or people integrating or deploying your code with other things.

> A better way to do this?

Yes.  See above.  (Though "better" in this context means more to your taste.)

Related (but not duplicate) Question:

- [The type MultipartEntity is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196292/the-type-multipartentity-is-deprecated)

---

<sup>1 - Unlike Sun / Oracle, the Apache HTTP Components folks *often* remove deprecated APIs after a period.  Ignore deprecation warnings in 3rd-party libraries at your peril ...</sup>