# Sending image with parameters in httpurl

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

This is the code i am using to attach my image with parameters :

```
  DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(
                        con.getOutputStream());
                if(bitmap!=null)
                {
                    request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);

                    request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_picture\";filename=\"profile_picture.jpg\"" + crlf);

                    request.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + crlf);
                    request.writeBytes(crlf);
                    byte[] pixels = new byte[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.getWidth(); ++i) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.getHeight(); ++j) {
                            //we're interested only in the MSB of the first byte,
                            //since the other 3 bytes are identical for B&W images
                            pixels[i + j] = (byte) ((bitmap.getPixel(i, j) & 0x80) >> 7);
                        }
                    }

                    request.write(pixels);//your image array here buddy
                    request.writeBytes(crlf);
                    request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);


                    request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
                    Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> set=params.valueSet();
                    Iterator itr = set.iterator();

                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)itr.next();

                        request.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+me.getKey().toString()+"\"" + crlf);
                        request.writeBytes(crlf);
                        request.writeBytes(me.getValue().toString());//your parameter value
                        request.writeBytes(crlf);
                        request.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary +
                                crlf);
                    }


                    request.flush();
                    request.close();


                }
```

and i am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11826317/5327912)

if i don't send image then the values are sent to the server perfectly, if i add image then i get that the text parameters are not been able to sent.

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to use `MultipartEntity`. with this you can send multipart in request.

Comment: MultipartEntity is deprecated, that's y i am not using it.

Comment: From the docs, you'll notice that you should use MultipartEntityBuilder as an alternative.

Comment: for reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196292/the-type-multipartentity-is-deprecated?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: at at the end we have to use HttpClient with multipartentitybuilder, and that is deprecated